# Removing Unused Desktops

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

After a recent and fresh Ubuntu 23.04 install (just Ubuntu, not Xubuntu, Lubuntu or other flavor) and seeing that it installed Gnome which I do not care for, I quickly installed Xfce and the Xfce goodies via the command line and switched to it. Seeing the boot options, there was `GNOME`, `Ubuntu` and `Xfce Session` and I want to get rid of the two I don't need. However, when I uninstalled Gnome using . . .

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell
```

. . . the system now boots only to a black screen.

Also, if I go to the root prompt by pressing Shift during the BIOS, then reboot from there, it somehow loads with the Ubuntu 22.04 logo in the lower left corner when this PC has never had that version on it! How do I get it to boot properly? I have no other PCs here as I am traveling and would like to get it back up and running.

Comment: You've provided few specifics as to how you installed Xfce & what you're wanting to use as your DM. Ubuntu Desktop uses GNOME & thus uses `gdm3` as DM as it uses the GNOME codebase, Xubuntu doesn't use it, but you don't mention installing Xubuntu code (only Xfce).  Your sessions maybe found in `/usr/share/xsessions/` but its unclear to me what you're actually running (ps: *I love multi desktop setups & switch some in & out in QA somewhat regularly too; how its done & packages used can matter*)

Comment: Those are good questions but as Ubuntu was installed several months ago, then Xfce was installed over a month ago, I did not make note of the details so I posted what I knew rather than guessing. That said, actually I DID mention Xubuntu in that it was the basic Ubuntu that was installed rather than Xubuntu. Since I do not at all care for the Gnome menuing system  that comes with Ubuntu, I wanted to use the same one that my other PCs have, which is Xfce, so that was installed by way of a terminal session. Once Xfce was installed, I put the nice lobster image back on as the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: You can always explore your `apt` logs for reminders (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) or if terminal you can view your bash `history` too..  Either way explore as I suggested `/usr/share/xsessions` where I have a `ubuntu.desktop` on my *mantic* system, a `dpkg -S /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` tells me its from `ubuntu-session` package.. (my box has Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu Desktop & more installed on it so I'd expect `ubuntu-session` installed).. FYI: I'd remove unwanted packages rather than just erase files in provided directory.

Comment: I edited the question.